# How to connect ckeditor to my site

Tags: webforms, textarea, ckeditor

I apologize if I'm repeating a question. please link to the location that contains the answer I'm looking for, because I couldn't find it.

I looked at the documentation, and it didn't help. http://docs.cksource.com/CKEditor_3.x/Developers_Guide/Minimum_Setup

http://www.elated.com/articles/adding-wysiwyg-editor-to-your-site/

link above is the tutorial I used to get the code below.

I'm struggling to find any good help and I've looked for an hour.

My Goal: to allow my users to click on a link that takes them to another page, where they can write notes and save them for their own personal use in the future. They will have their own login, so their notes are only visible to them and people they give access to.

After researching on StackOverflow, I feel like **ckeditor** would be the best tool for the job.

Here are my attempts at installing it. (ps. I have downloaded the folder from the site so I doubt "installing" is the correct term.)

My Script tags in the head:

```
<script type = "text/javascript" src="ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>
<script>
window.onload = function () {
CKEDITOR.replaceAll('wysiwyg');
};

</script>
```

My first webform attempt:

```
CKEDITOR.replace( 'fieldname');
        <textarea id="userNotes" class="wysiwyg"><strong>test</strong></textarea>
```

My WebForm copy paste from tutorial above:

```
<form action="form_handler.php" method="post">
<div>
  <textarea cols="80" rows="10" id="content" name="content"> 
    &lt;h1&gt;Article Title&lt;/h1&gt;
    &lt;p&gt;Here's some sample text&lt;/p&gt;
  </textarea>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    CKEDITOR.replace( 'articleContent' );
  </script>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</div>
```

Everything I have tried so far gives me a textarea with plain text inside, and that is not how it is supposed to look.

To reiterate my question, how do I properly setup/link my ckeditor files inside my html file and web form to get ckeditor to actually work?

Question Part two: Am I even approaching my goal correctly? is ckeditor a good solution for my goal to allow users to create notes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
CKEDITOR.replace('content');
```

This is the ID and name of the textbox so you need to target that.

```
<textarea cols="80" rows="10" id="content" name="content"> 
 &lt;h1&gt;Article Title&lt;/h1&gt;
 &lt;p&gt;Here's some sample text&lt;/p&gt;
</textarea>
<script type="text/javascript">
 CKEDITOR.replace('content');
</script>
```

Comment: Yup. I'm embarrassed. Thank you.

Comment: I guess I could say the guy who made the tutorial should be embarrassed because.. technically he made the mistake, I just didn't catch it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the [documentation](http://docs.cksource.com/CKEditor_3.x/Developers_Guide/ASP.NET/Integration_Beginners). I am assuming you're using ASP.Net.

If you follow the above tutorial, you can then add CKEditor by:

```
<CKEditor:CKEditorControl ID="CKEditor1" runat="server">
</CKEditor:CKEditorControl>
```

Comment: I'm still a Noob, I'll dig into whatever asp.net is, since I have no idea. I'm assuming it's some sort of backend thing.

Comment: Hmmm... sure, if you're using Webforms, you're actually using Asp.Net.